# Creating a Texture with "glTexImage2D" in OpenGL-ES with C++ on Android NDK causes Problems

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es, android-ndk

I tried creating textures with following C++ code with the Android NDK:

```
glGenTextures(1, (GLuint*)&index);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, index);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);


glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, cx, cy, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid*)d);
```

It works for a while and then the program just exits. There are no error messages or anything else. The program just ends.

I tried a loop with only the creation of the required textures and it does run as expected if I remove the line with the "glTexImage2D" command (of course the textures are not created and cannot be used then) but exits without warning when the command is there.

Could anyone give me any kind of advice on this behaviour and why the glTexImage2D doesn't just fail and return an error message that I can get with glGetError(); ?

Answer (score 0):

> It works for a while and then the program just exits.

Do you mean, you reupload the textures for each frame? If so, why? Only upload a texture once before you need it. You can later re-/use it by simply calling glBindTexture again.

Comment: Its for testing purposes only. I want to see how many textures I can create until the video memory is full and OpenGL starts to swap them. I usually can see a huge performance drop when that happens though I only tried that in java so far.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it helps, but I had such issues when I tried to use opengl in more than one thread. Perhaps take a look at this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I only have 1 thread doing all the work.

Answer (score 0):

Android, in general, does not have a page file (the is no HDD on mobile phone. Also the memory is shared between graphics accelerator and CPU. So, the OS just kills your process when it ate all the memory (with textures). You can see it in a LogCat: before your process every other dies. It looks like a bug in a driver or OpenGL impl.